# arcpy.Resample_management: Using cell size from another raster dataset

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.4

I am using arcgis 10.4. I want resample my geotif image same as resolution to a dem. I have the example from http://pro.arcgis.com/de/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/resample.htm.

```
arcpy.Resample_management("c:/data/image.tif", "resample.tif", "10 20", "NEAREST")
```

Is it possible to use the name of my dem instead direct cellsize as input. Of course I could read cellsize first and use it for the tool.

Did anyone have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this if you want to use code:

```
import arcpy

workspace = r"X:\Test\myGDB.gdb"
myReferenceRaster = r"X:\Test\myGDB.gdb\myReferenceRaster"

arcpy.env.workspace = workspace
arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace = workspace
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Read cell size in X direction
cellSizeX = arcpy.Describe(myReferenceRaster).meanCellWidth

# Read cell size in Y direction
cellSizeY = arcpy.Describe(myReferenceRaster).meanCellHeight

# Resample
cellSizeXY = u"{} {}".format(cellSizeX, cellSizeY)
arcpy.Resample_management("c:/data/image.tif", "resample.tif", cellSizeXY, "NEAREST")
```

The `arcpy.Describe()` function offers a wide range of possibilites for such purposes. More information here: [ArcGIS Online Help - Describe](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/describe.htm)